# Mobile Broadband not showing in Network Manager

Tags: network-manager, mobile-broadband

I have very big problem with mobile broadband connections...
I tried on my laptop to connect and searched the web for possible solution, but didn't found it.

The problem is that i DON'T have the menu Mobile Broadband. I have only Wireless and Wired connection. I even don't see the Enable Mobile Broadband! I had success with one USB modem with sakis3g, but on my new Alcate didn't worked.

I've tried also on new freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 on PC, and again - no menu at all for Mobile Broadband! When I open "Network connections" I have menu Mobile Broadbands and when I add a connection - nothing happens, it shows me "last used - never"

In addition to add - In "Networks" I can't add Mobile Broadband, I only have Wired, Wireless, Network Proxy and when I try to add ne type it only shows VPN option.

When I saw I didn't have "Mobile Broadband" in network manager I tried to reinstall it and did big mess, now my menu is very strange (I thing I didn't installed the amd64 at first and that's why it's so weird )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USB Modem was recognised as Flash Memory and that was the problem! The only thing you have to do is this:

Disk Utility -> The USB FLASH drive(there will be 2 devices for you Model, choose the CD/DVD drive) and UnMount it!

That's it! After this wait a little bit and you're ready!

Answer (score 1):

Following packages are needed for the `network-manager` to work properly. If one of them is not problems arise. Specially it needs `modemmanager` to work with Mobile Broadband. Try with installing all. Terminal will install the deficient.

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg multiarch-support dbus dnsmasq-base iproute iputils-arping isc-dhcp-client libc6 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libglib2.0-0 libgudev-1.0-0 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libsoup2.4-1 lsb-base policykit-1 udev upstart-job wpasupplicant crda iptables modemmanager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp ppp avahi-autoipd
```