# mobile broadband not appearing on system menu

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband, wwan

I inserted a sim card in the sim card slot of my laptop and was expecting the mobile broadband option to appear on the system menu, but it doesn't. I have a Fibocom L860 and WWAN is also enabled via bios so I'm thinking that it should work. As far as I know, Fibocom L860 should be supported in Ubuntu.

I checked by running `mmcli -L` on the terminal and it says that there were no modems found. I also tried to run `sudo modem-manager.mmcli -L`, but I keep getting `error: couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied`. I tried installing a modem manager gui, but it's still not able to recognize my sim card.

I tried solving my problem using [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328937/mobile-broadband-not-showing-in-network-manager) but there's no CD/DVD drive option appearing, so I couldn't proceed with it.

<strike>I am not sure why this problem is happening. Is there a way to check if the problem is with the sim card, the sim card slot, or anything else?</strike>

Edit:
I switched the OS to Windows to check if it was a hardware problem, but my sim card was easily recognized and I was able to use it to access the internet.

Switching back to Ubuntu, I entered `nm-connection-editor` on the terminal and added a mobile broadband connection for my sim card. I also tried running mobile broadband by entering `sudo service mobile-broadband-connection start`, but I still cannot access the Internet, and mobile broadband option still isn't appearing in the system menu either.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Do you have the driver ? Apparently, it is quiet hard to use Fibocom L850 with Linux and X1 Carbon : is it also difficult with Fibocom L860 ? Search about Fibocom L850 and you may have some answers. I didn't find any Linux driver.

Comment: i checked via terminal and wwan driver is enabled. according to this, L860 should work: https://www.reddit.com/r/LinuxOnThinkpad/comments/c3lxky/fibocom_l860gl_under_linux/
it's difficult to find answers regarding 850, and 860 seems to redirect me to 850 so it feels like a dead end

Comment: See also: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-status-of-Fibocom-L850-Gl/m-p/4082434/highlight/true#M11025; https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-status-of-Fibocom-L850-Gl/m-p/4082434/highlight/true#M11025

Comment: @NikosAlexandris thanks! i suspected as much. i don't think they'll be supporting L850 at all, but maybe hopefully for L860 they'll have support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried generating an automated test and mobile broadband is missing some modules. seems like it's not yet fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours and managed to get it working using the following command:

`sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x03f0 -p 0x9d1d -u3` (change the `03f0` and `9d1d` to the ID displayed for the device when you run `lsusb`)

If this is successful, then mobile broadband will show up in the system menu.